# What is difference between 'glad' and 'pleased'?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am studying English writing.

I am translated my language to English.

My book's answer is "I am pleased to meet you"

My answer was "I am glad to meet you"

Is this same sentence?
Does it have same meaning?

If my grammer is poor in this question, please correct my sentence.

If you correct my grammer, it will be very helpfull.

Thank you

Comment: The usual fixed form people use is *I am pleased to meet you.* Occasionally somebody might say *I am glad to meet you*. There's really no difference in meaning.

Comment: [correction: I am translating from my language to English]

Answer (score 3):

"Glad" can have an element of relief about it.

If you meet someone who is (or you hope will be) pleasant and agreeable to talk to you can say "I am pleased to meet you".

If you have some problem and and you finally find someone who may be able to help you might say "I am glad to meet you".

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ELL!

Your grammar is not too bad! I've corrected some spelling mistakes and made it more continuous.

> I am studying English writing and **have translated** (or **am translating** if you are *still* translating it!)  the sentence below
> from my language into English.
>
> According to my book it should be "I am pleased to meet you," but I
> translated it as "I am glad to meet you." Do they both mean the same?
>
> If the gr**a**mmar in my question is poor, please correct it. If you do,
> it will be very helpfu**l**.

I agree with Nemo about the words *glad* and *pleased*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in meaning.

You can use either.

But "I'm pleased to meet you" is the more common expression.

If you are learning English you should say "I'm pleased to meet you".